# rqt Fatal IO error 2

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i try to use the command:

```
 $ rqt_graph
```

or any other rqt command i get the error:

```
python: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.
```

I already have try to follow what they did here:
[https://answers.ros.org/question/300329/rqt-python-fatal-io-error-2-no-such-file-or-directory-on-x-server-00/]

But i will receive the same error what can it be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320775/rqt-fatal-io-error-2/) by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem of this error was that i did not run roscore.

---

Originally posted by [JoeryTemmink](https://answers.ros.org/users/40775/joerytemmink/) with karma: 18 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0